# Exclude Empty Empty Cells From Multiple Filters Formula In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

With this formula, if any of the filters has no results, an empty cell is included in the column of results.
**How do I exclude empty results so that does not show?**

```
=UNIQUE({  
IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B,Sheet1!$A$2:$A=D1));   
IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet2!$B$2:$B,Sheet2!$A$2:$A=D1));   
IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet3!$B$2:$B,Sheet3!$A$2:$A=D1))  
})
```

e.g.

Results Sheet1
Results Sheet1
Results Sheet1
------------- empty cell from no results for sheet2
Results Sheet3
Results Sheet3
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming D1 contains a string, try:

```
=UNIQUE (QUERY( {Sheet1!$A$2:$B; Sheet2!$A$2:$B; Sheet3!$A$2:$B}, "Select Col2 where Col1 = '"&D1&"' and Col2 <>''", 0))
```

If D1 is a number, use

```
where Col1 = "&D1&""
```

and see if that helps?